# Отскок в обратную сторону

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно чтобы сфера отскакивал в противоположную сторону при касании
моего игрока.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public GameObject Ball;//мяч
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {    
        if (col.collider.name == "Ball")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо и извините, если криво сформировал вопрос.

Comment: для этого не нужно писать кода вообще. Для этого нужно настроить физические материалы и повесить rigitbody

Comment: Спасибо но я хотел бы менять скорость мяча из кода

Comment: тогда нужно смотреть в OnCollisionExit и там уже смотреть направление физического отскакивания и добавлять импульс в эту сторону. Но говорю сразу что это более чем глупая затея, лучше все настроить материалами.